# flutter error javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: android, flutter, dart

when I try to build apk in my flutter project
the terminal show me a lot of lines problems in Gradle I tried to use `flutter build apk` no sound null safety and also the project is related to firebase

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
> Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> > javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
> - with linked exception:
> [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Fin pr�matur�e du fichier.]

my dependencies

```
version: 1.0.0+1
```

environment:
sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
firebase: ^9.0.3
firebase_core: ^1.15.0
firebase_auth: ^3.3.16
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.